# Logitech G HUB script keeps repeating

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Whenever I have a script to run with a specific program, it repeats if I alt-tab out of the application and then back in. For example, if for Google Chrome I have a script like this:

```
PressMouseButton(1)
ReleaseMouseButton(1)
```

If I switch to Microsoft Word and then back to Google Chrome, the script will repeat, causing the mouse to click again.

How can I solve this so that it only does the script once per application launch?

Comment: GHUB does not monitor application launches.  GHUB reinitializes the profile every time you switch focus.  So, if you alt-tab and focus jumps from app1 to app2, GHUB deactivates profile for app1 and activates profile for app2.  If there is no specific profile assigned to an app, the default profile is used.  If app1 and app2 belong to the same profile, profile does not switch,

Comment: What exactly you want your script to do at the Chrome launch?